# (MacOS) Watchman unable to access file in Downloads

Tags: npm, expo, watchman

I'm currently attempting to code an Expo app and upon running "npm start" I get the following error:

`Error: std::__1::system_error: open: [filepath to project]: Operation not permitted`

Everything was working perfectly fine until I accidentally clicked "Don't Allow" on a popup that said "Watchman would like to access files in your Downloads folder."

I have granted Watchman full disk access in the Security & Privacy section, I've tried reinstalling watchman, and I've also tried restarting my computer, but the error persists.

I also attempted `sudo watchman watch .` but then I get the error `the owner of /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state is uid 501 and doesn't match your euid 0`

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemingly resolved itself, I guess the issue had something to do with MacOS itself but it self-corrected.